# Font over font strange border

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have 2 font icons. 
They are positioned absolute one above other. 
Let's say that **icon-A** is above **icon-B**.
Icon-B should never be visible.

Somehow **icon-A** is visible. Strange border is visible. Can someone explain me why and how to fix this?

HTML:

```
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
div {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 200px;

  i {
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 11;

    &:last-child {
      z-index: 11;
      color: #ddd;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is codepen:
https://codepen.io/balancana/pen/mvRKPM
https://codepen.io/balancana/pen/mvRKvK

I don't think that problem is with font because I tried other fonts too.

PREVIEW:

[image]

Comment: i think this is because there is a small gradient calculated to smooth the border of the letters.. note that the color gets deeper when you stack more and more icons.. what are you trying to achieve btw?

Comment: I'm working on custom rating element, something like this (https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/Screen%20Shot%202016-08-04%20at%205.22.57%20PM.png)

Comment: if you really need both displayed (to show half a star i guess), you can make the one that will always be behind just a slightly smaller in size. shouldn't be noticeable. Or put the darker color in front following Nick Parsons's comment

Comment: Something to note. This only seems to be a problem for when the element on the top is a light color. (eg lightgrey or lightgreen) but doesn't seem to be present on darker colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helped me most is using: `-webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.01em;`

It's not stable full (can be future changes on this css property) and it's not working on IE.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke-width

Answer (score 1):

Are the font icons exactly the same size ? Because it looks like they are in the same position so there should be no problem…

Or maybe you can solve this by putting one of them with `visibility: hidden;` ?

EDIT: Well they are the same size, but the problem might be that the color makes the font more wide… When putting the red one above the grey one, I Don't see the grey one anymore…

Comment: That's interesting, `visibility: hidden` is not solution for me, because i'm working on rating element and in some cases I need both icon to be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the goal is to be able to makes half stars, i see 2 solutions:

- put the darker color in front (examples 1 and 2)
- make the darker color which is behind a little smaller, this won't be noticeable (examples 3 and 4)

```css
div#test1 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 200px;
}
div#test1 i {
  color: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 11;
}
div#test1 i:last-child {
  z-index: 11;
  color: red;
}

div#test2 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 200px;
}
div#test2 i {
  color: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 11;
}
div#test2 i:last-child {
  z-index: 11;
  color: red;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}



div#test3 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 196px;
}
div#test3 i {
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  z-index: 11;
}
div#test3 i:last-child {
  z-index: 11;
  font-size: 200px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #ddd;
}



div#test4 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 196px;
}
div#test4 i {
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  z-index: 11;
}
div#test4 i:last-child {
  z-index: 11;
  font-size: 200px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #ddd;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="test1">
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</div>
<div style="height: 200px;"></div>
<div id="test2">
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</div>
<div style="height: 200px;"></div>
<div id="test3">
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</div>
<div style="height: 200px;"></div>
<div id="test4">
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
</div>
```